# Please convert this code to TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I need to convert the Nodejs code below into a TypeScript. I will be glad if someone can help me with this or an idea of how I can achieve this. I have done all sorts of tries but not working.

```
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');

function request(callback) {
var path='/v1/payments';
var data = querystring.stringify( {
    'authentication.userId' : '52542LesMor',
    'authentication.password' : '123456',
    'AuthId' : '9965652',
    'amount' : '30',
    'currency' : 'ZAR',
    'paymentBrand' : 'VISA',
    'paymentType' : 'DB',
    'card.number' : '8500000040000000',
});
var options = {
    port: 5986,
    host: 'me.leslie.com',
    path: path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};
var postRequest = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        jsonRes = JSON.parse(chunk);
        return callback(jsonRes);
    });
});
postRequest.write(data);
postRequest.end();
}

request(function(responseData) {
console.log(responseData);
});
```

Comment: Most JavaScript is already valid TypeScript by default; which part exactly are you stuck on?  Broad "please do this for me" questions generally aren't well-received here, but if you can clarify what you're having trouble with and what you've already tried to solve it you might get a better response.

Comment: @LeslieMortu I hope you can accept the answer or at least elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Converting from JavaScript to TypeScript can be pain-free. 
Any problems I have encountered with TypeScript in `node` are generally of the node `API`, `modules` and `build-tools` nature (I want my cake and eat it too).
<sub>So not really a problem with TypeScript</sub>

Without more specific information, I thought I would just have some `copypasta` fun in the [typescriptlang `playground`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

```js
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

request(callback: () => {}) {
  const path = '/v1/payments';
  const data = querystring.stringify({
    'authentication.userId': '52542LesMor',
    'authentication.password': '123456',
    'AuthId': '9965652',
    'amount': '30',
    'currency': 'ZAR',
    'paymentBrand': 'VISA',
    'paymentType': 'DB',
    'card.number': '8500000040000000',
  });
  const options = {
    port: 5986,
    host: 'me.leslie.com',
    path: path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': data.length
    }
  };
  const postRequest = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      jsonRes = JSON.parse(chunk);
      return callback(jsonRes);
    });
  });
  postRequest.write(data);
  postRequest.end();
}

const aCallback = (responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData);
    request(aCallback);
}
```

*very mildly edited for stylistic preference.*

#### Edit:

Hope it shows a more `TypeScripty` style that I picked up after learning the language recently. (TS-ee? [Swifty?](https://alhazmy13.github.io/swift-is-like-typescript/) Tazzy?)

I also usually like to `const` every part of a function I use (the `return` value), but nice <sub>performant</sub> immutability may require an extra library or more functional ways that I don't find as conducive in `Angular` (I hope to finally get to rebuilding projects in `React` soon).